# UnsupportedEncodingException: UTF_8 Jdom

Tags: java, xml, encoding, jdom

i have this code java

```
String fichier= "movies.xml";
builder = new SAXBuilder();
xmlFile = new File(fichier);
document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
```

but when i execute this code i have an exception about encodding

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Octet 2 de la séquence UTF-8 à 4 octets non valide.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:701)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:473)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1793)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipChar(XMLEntityScanner.java:1463)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2824)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:905)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:884)
```

at ligne "document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);"

so, how can i resolve this problem

thank you in advance

Comment: Does `movies.xml` by any chance start with the line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF_8"?>` ?

Comment: yes movies.xml is it

Comment: The new error message suggests that the actual encoding of your xml file is different from the declared encoding. Either change the encoding of the xml file to `UTF-8` or change the encoding delcaration to the actual encoding of the file.

Comment: how can i change it , can you give me an exemple?

Comment: Most text editors have the option to change the encoding. For example if you use Notepad++ then open the file you want to change, click on the `Encoding` menu and select `Convert to UTF-8 without BOM`. See this link for more details: http://superuser.com/a/762475

Comment: BTW, the title of the question doesn't make much sense without the original error message.
I suggest you edit your question to put it back (and what you did to get rid of it). That way this question is more helpful for people who might have the same problem as you initially had.

Comment: it works thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summing up the comments:

**Regarding the first error message** (`UnsupportedEncodingException: UTF_8`)

`UTF_8` is not a valid encoding, use `UTF-8` instead. In your xml file replace the line

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF_8"?>`

with

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

**Regarding the second error message** (`MalformedByteSequenceException`)

The encoding of the xml has to match the declared encoding. Convert the encoding of the xml file to `UTF-8`.